# Updating serialized data from a Wordpress database

Tags: wordpress, serialization

I moved a WordrPress website from one server and domain to another, but into the database I still have the old paths and I want to update them to the new values. The real problem is that the content I need to change is serialized, so I cannot do a global find and replace like:
`http://my-old-domain.com/` replaced with `http://my-newest-domain.com` because I have to replace things like this:

`s:755:\"<img class=\"size-medium\" src=\"http://my-old-domain.com/esthetique/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/logo-fundal-300x64.png\" ...`

to

`s:755:\"<img class=\"size-medium\" src=\"http://my-newest-domain.com/esthetique/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/logo-fundal-300x64.png\" ...`

`newest` has 6 characters while `old` had 3 characters, so all the `s:...` part needs to be increased with 3. I could do this manually, but there are 1470 places where this needs to be changed and the `s:...` part takes different values.
Can you please advise if there is an easy way to do this? I cannot change by hand all of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use many popular search and replace plugin to change you domain linked path. For ex -[Search & Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/)

Comment: I tried this, but it seems it removes also the slash (\\) before the quotes. Ex: `s:11:\"column-link\"` becomes `s:11:"column-link"`. Anyway, after the change, everything seems to be fine. Can you please confirm that the removing of the slash I mentioned will not cause any further problems? Thanks!

Comment: No it will not cause any further issues, its happened because of json encode type format.